# Not able to set browser locale to java ResourceBundle

Tags: java, utf-8, resourcebundle

I am writing website in 3 languages i.e. English, Arabic and Persian. I am trying to show the user this website in relative language. For example if the browser language is Arabic then website will be displayed in Arabic and if its is Persian then Persian website will be display

Here what I did so far:

```
    private Locale locale(){
        Locale locale=null;     
            if(country == null){
                locale = request.getLocale();
                if(locale.equals("ar")){                    
                    locale      = new Locale("ar", "AE");                   
                }
                else if(locale.equals("fa")){                   
                    locale      = new Locale("fa", "IR");
                }
                else if(locale.equals("en")){                   
                    language    = "en";
                    locale      = new Locale("en", "US");
                }

            }else{          
                locale = new Locale(language, country);
            }
System.out.println("return---locale=>"+locale);         
    return locale;
    }
```

This method printing `locale=>ar`

```
ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("LabelBundles.Labels",locale());
```

`if(country == null){}` block is not working whereas `else{

                locale = new Locale(language, country);
            }`
is working fine.

2) `locale = request.getLocale();` output is "ar" whilst `locale = new Locale();` requires two values that is `language`_`COUNTRY` so why its giving output as "ar" only without country?

Please advise and thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

request.getLocale() returns a Locale, not a String. So

```
locale.equals("ar")
```

will always be false: only a String can be equal to a String. And only a Locale can be equal to a Locale.

You can however do

```
if (locale.getLanguage().equals("ar"))
```

Regarding your second question, it's of course answered by [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html). If you read it, you'll learn that a locale is a language, + an optional country, + an optional variant. And there is a constructor taking only a language as argument.

Read the javadoc. That's how you learn.

Comment: Thanks from the bottom of my heart. Its working fine now. You said well about javadocs. I realize that the main problem is we don't bother to read javadocs that's why facing such problems.